# What type of navigation in Prism is this?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

What type of navigation in Prism is this:

1) When I click on a toggle button, one control disappears and another
one appears. That is, the visibility for one control is set to false
and for the other to true. It is a toggle button, so when you keep
clicking it, you will switch between the controls.

2) What about this case... I have more panes in a window, and a toggle button.
This toggle button shows/hides a single pane.

I am new to Prism and confused are these considered navigation in the sense of Prism,
and what type?

Answer (score 1):

**Prism** would consider this navigation as ***Stated-Based Navigation***, although no **Prism** related work would be needed in this case. This type of **Navigation** is defined for updates that may occur in the current `View` like state changes, style or user's interaction without moving to another `View`.

Instead, ***View-Based Navigation*** is considered for switching between `Views` which are registered in the same `Region`, giving the possibility of going back or forward through them.

You could find useful the following **Prism Guide** chapter regarding both types of **Navigation** and how each one could be accomplished:

- [Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.